# Improve execution time in GS AppScript (loop over 2 array for comparing and filtering)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am working on some data that needs cleaning
I have 2 source files (google sheets) with no common index (ID) but with last names.
file 1 is a  list of the names and emails for the company (≃2500 lines
file 2 is a list of the names and the company ID.(≃5000 lines)

I am reading in the 2 files into 2 arrays.
my basic logic is

> for every line in file 1,
>   compare with each line in file 2
>   if name is == ,
>   compare firstname,
>   if both are == write to new array

the issues, is that I only get through about 2000 lines before a timeout.
I do not think that i need 6 minutes to execute this so I must have some inefficient code.
Value positions in arrays are predetermined (from files)
thanks for your feedback

```
function compareData(emailList,employeeList) {
      var results = []
      for (e=0;e<emailList.length;e++){
        for (i=0;i<employeeList.length;i++){
          var lastName = emailList[e][1]; 
          var elementPos = employeeList[i].map(function(x) { return x; }).indexOf(lastName); //compare Last Name
          if (elementPos !== -1){
            // compare first names
            if (employeeList[i][3]==emailList[e][0]){
              //First Name & Last Name are ==  
              // compare email extention
              if (emailList[e][2].indexOf("@mydomain.com")!== -1){ 
                //Put line in results table
                results.push([employeeList[i][0],employeeList[i][1],employeeList[i][2],employeeList[i][3],emailList[e][2],emailList[e][1],emailList[e][0],"FALSE"]) 
                } else {
                results.push([employeeList[i][0],employeeList[i][1],employeeList[i][2],employeeList[i][3],emailList[e][2],emailList[e][1],emailList[e][0],"TRUE"])  
               };
            }
          };    

        }
      }
      return results;
    }
```

here

Comment: in writing the question, i realised that i don't need the .map iteration as I stated myself, value positions in the array are predetermined.
So i can substitue out the .map statement for a simple if().
execution adds about 200 lines.. but still far from my required 5000...

Comment: Is your script in the question the latest one? If it's different, please update it. And I think that if the sample data is shown, it will help users think of your solution or workaround. If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.